# Modifying records in groupby query

Tags: ms-access

I am creating application for ToDo list and I have there three tables. Table with ToDos ("tblToDo"), table with Labels ("tblLabels") and mapping table where each ToDo can have one or more label ("tblToDoLabels").

I need to find ToDos that have two concrete labels. So I used IN() statement, but that finds me records that have one of the looking labels that is why I used GroupBy statement and other condition that the Item has to be twice in the table. It works great, but now I cannot modify the records in the query. Is there a way to search for this data I need and still be able to modify the records in the query?

Here is SQL for the query I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblToDo.ID, tblToDo.FROM tblToDo 
LEFT JOIN tblToDoLabels ON tblToDo.ID = tblToDoLabels.ToDo
WHERE tblToDoLabels.Label In (3,20)
GROUP BY tblToDo.ID, tblToDo.ToDo
HAVING Count(tblToDoLabels.ToDo)=2;
```

Comment: An aggregating query cannot be updated, so retrieve the IDs of the ToDos and run an update query for all or each of these passing the ID(s) as parameter for a filter.

Comment: Yes that was my backup plan :) I was just wondering if there is any way around that. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you need to update?

Comment: I have it linked to the form where I need to change the selected data, but I found a way around it when I run update query with change of some values, it would be just easier to do it through bound query :)